# anaconda manual update stuck on fetching pywinpty

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm using Anaconda version 1.6.8 on Windows 7 and decided to update it manually, and it seems that the current version is 1.9.12 . To update, I used the update button on Anaconda navigator.

but it seems to be stuck on a 54KB file called pywinpty-0.5.7 and it's trying to fetch since hours. apparently, stopping the update will roll back all the operation. What should I do to resolve or bypass?

[image]

Comment: No ideas why? it's still stuck there

Comment: I don't see any option other than stopping it. After that, try using command line (e.g., Anaconda Prompt), first updating Conda (`conda update -n base -c defaults conda`), then retry updating navigator (`conda update -n base -c anaconda anaconda-navigator`). I'm not guaranteeing that will do any better - just that it tends to be more reliable.